# Wrong Color Encoding In Airflow Logs

Tags: python, airflow

I am using Airflow `task.virtualenv` but my logs on the UI shows some weird characters from the background color encoding like `[0m`. Here is part of the log.

```
[2023-09-18, 14:05:42 EDT] {process_utils.py:190} INFO -     'Date': 'Mon, 18 Sep 2023 18:05:42 GMT'
[2023-09-18, 14:05:42 EDT] {process_utils.py:190} INFO -     'Content-Length': '300'[0m
[2023-09-18, 14:05:42 EDT] {process_utils.py:190} INFO - 2023-09-18 18:05:42,477 - sqlalchemy.engine.Engine - INFO - SELECT CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS VARCHAR)
[2023-09-18, 14:05:42 EDT] {process_utils.py:190} INFO - [[34m2023-09-18T18:05:42.477+0000[0m] {[34mbase.py:[0m1863} INFO[0m - SELECT CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS VARCHAR)[0m
[2023-09-18, 14:05:42 EDT] {process_utils.py:190} INFO - 2023-09-18 18:05:42,478 - sqlalchemy.engine.Engine - INFO - [raw sql] ()
```

My DAG looks like approximately this:

```py
@task.virtualenv(task_id='callable_virtualenv')
    def callable_virtualenv(ds=None):
        import logging
        logger = logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy')
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(handler)
        
        # read data using SQLAlchemy
```

Note I set the output to `sys.stdout` according to the 2nd and 3rd bullet points in the guide [writing-to-task-logs-from-your-code](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/logging-monitoring/logging-tasks.html#writing-to-task-logs-from-your-code).

I found in this [discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/588600/in-this-0330132m-vt100-style-ansi-escape-sequences-what-is-the-01-and-the-m), the [0m] character comes is probably part of the ANSI escape code. But I am not familiar with encoding. How can I fix this?

Also, I am not sure whether the color settings come from the Airflow root logger or the `logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)` I added in the above sample code. Disabling the color should work for me.

My airflow environment is apache/airflow:2.7.1 (Python 3.8) the official Docker Hub.